# Sampling in Matlab

Tags: r, matlab, sampling

So let me start off by saying that I do not have the statistics toolbox for Matlab so I am trying to find a way to work around this.  In any case, what I am trying to do is to replicate the R `sample` function.  For example, in R

```
> x = sample(1:5,20,replace=T,prob=c(.1,.1,.1,.1,.6))
> x
 [1] 5 5 5 4 5 2 5 5 1 5 5 5 5 5 5 3 5 1 5 5
```

so I am sampling the integers 1,2,3,4,5 with replacement.  But furthermore, I am sampling each integer with a certain proportion, i.e., the integer 5 should be sampled about 60% of the time.

So my question that I would like to find a solution to is how to achieve this in Matlab?

Comment: Easiest solution: buy stats toolbox; call `randsample`. http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/randsample.html :)

Comment: Even easier (and cheaper): use R. If you cannot or don't want to avoid Matlab you can [integrate R scripts in Matlab](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:callingr:matlab).

Comment: @RichieCotton: actually, Matlab's `randsample` doesn't support weighted sampling without replacement.

Comment: I am not able to buy the stat toolbox and the original code I wrote is in R but I am now converting it to Matlab so I don't want to integrate R scripts into it.

Comment: [Here](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/random.c) you can look at the C function used by R.

Comment: Another cheesy Matlab solution: find someone who has the stats toolbox.  He will thus have the source matlab function code for `randsample` hiding in a directory.  Copy said code (it's a text m-file) and paste as a file in you personal matlab working directory. While you need a license to be able to traverse a toolbox directory from the console, you do not need (functionally, as opposed to legally ) a license to execute m-files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can perform weighted sampling with replacement (something Matlab's `randsample` doesn't support, btw);

```
function r = sample(pop,n,weights)
%# each weight creates a "bin" of defined size. If the value of a random number
%# falls into the bin, we pick the value

%# turn weights into a normed cumulative sum
csWeights = cumsum(weights(:))/sum(weights);
csWeights = [0;csWeights(1:end-1)];

%# for each value: pick a random number, check against weights
idx = sum(bsxfun(@ge,rand(1,n),csWeights),1);

r = pop(idx);
```

Comment: @user2005253: Note that this approach creates a n-by-length(pop) array temporarily. If that means you may run out of memory, you should preassign `r`, create a vector of random numbers of length `n` and then perform `r(i)=pop(sum(randVec(i)>=csWeights)` inside the loop.

Answer (score 3):

The unweighted case is easy using `randi`.

```
function r = sample(pop, n)

imax = length(pop);
index = randi(imax, n, 1);
r = pop(index);

end
```

In the weighted case, something like this should do the trick:

```
function r = sample(pop, n, prob)

cumprob = cumsum(prob);
r = zeros(1, n);
for i = 1:n
  index = find(rand < cumprob, 1, 'last');
  r(i) = pop(index);
end

end
```

Comment: Haven't got MATLAB handy at the moment, so the code is completely  untested.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to make your own `sample` function:

```
function x = sample(v, n, p)

pc = cumsum(p) / sum(p);
r = rand(1,n);
x = zeros(1,n);
for i = length(pc):-1:1
    x(r<pc(i)) = v(i);
end
```

It's not exactly efficient, but it does what you want. Call it like so:

```
v = [1 2 3 4 5];
p = [.1 .1 .1 .1 .6];
n = 20;
x = sample(v,n,p);
```